# Modim DeRabanan - UThHonnenu or UThKayemeinu?

Tags: tefilla, synagogue, shemoneh-esrei, nuschaot

There is a very common poster that I've seen in virtually every Shul I've been in over the past 10-15 years.  Unfortunately, I cannot find a photo at the moment.  It is a (generally laminated,) white poster with black lettering, with the words for Modim DeRabanan on it.  It tends to be placed on the wall of the Shul as an aid to the casual person who, like many of us, put down or closed his or her Siddur during Hazarath HaShatz and is unprepared to read Modim when the Hazan gets up to that point, and needs to read it inside due to a lack of memorization of the Modim DeRabanan or for greater ease in remembering (and therefore concentrating on) it.

However, virtually every version of this poster I have seen uses the exact same text (and font, spacing, etc.; in other words, they're all prints of the same original), and the text uses the word UThHonnenu (and favor us), in the line after we have expressed praise for G-d for "Having let us live and having sustained us", in the line that asks for this to continue, "So may You (G-d) allow us to live *and favor us*..."  But this is inconsistent with the previous praise.  We have praised HaShem for *sustaining us*.  Not only that, but in virtually every (Nusah Ashkenaz) Siddur I've ever seen, the text *is consistent* with the preceding line of praise!  Which one is it?  Is this poster from a different Nusah?  Was there a change at some point in recent Siddur printings and this poster is from an older, then-common text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is indeed the standard Sephardic nusach, according to [Wikipedia](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%90%D7%94#.D7.A0.D7.95.D7.A1.D7.97_.D7.9E.D7.95.D7.93.D7.99.D7.9D_.D7.93.D7.A8.D7.91.D7.A0.D7.9F_.D7.9B.D7.99.D7.95.D7.9D). Rambam ([Hil. Tefillah 9:4](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=2&hilchos=7&perek=9&halocha=4&hilite=)) has it this way, and [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42809&st=&pgnum=142)'s an example from a Spanish-Portuguese siddur.